# Does the size, direction, etc. of symbols make them different if the meaning is the same?

Tags: formal-languages

Does the direction/size of a symbol matter if we are writing down the alphabet for a formal language?

What I mean is, we have two formulas, $a<b$ and $b>a$. In that case, is $<$ a different symbol than $>$ and should these two be written as separate symbols in the alphabet.

Or if we have two symbols which mean exactly the same thing, but have different size (e.g. parentheses due to aesthetical reasons), should both of them be written down as separate symbols in the alphabet?

Comment: Size, they say, does not matter. As to $\lt$ and $\gt$, I would consider them different. It is true that $a\lt b$ if and only if $b\gt a$, but the relations $\lt$ and $\gt$ are different. As a more striking example, if $a\lt b$, then the interval $[a,b]$ is the familiar object, while $[b,a]$ is considered to be empty.  And $a\mid b$ ($a$ divides $b$) is not at all equivalent to $b\mid a$.

Comment: Though @André is right, it's also true that sometimes a relation $\lt$ or $\le$ is introduced and then for convenience inequalities may be written using $\gt$ or $\ge$, not with the intention of introducing a new relation or a new symbol but with $a\gt b$ being regarded as synonymous with $b\lt a$. You'll have to decide in the individual case whether this is what's being done.

Comment: Sometimes size does matter. For example the symbols $\cup$ and $\bigcup$ are used differently.

Comment: Then again, note that a formula such as $\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$ is far from what a formal language describes: a *linear* sequence of symbols. For a very formal treatment, all our everyday formulas have to be transformed into sequences of symbols, not some two-dimensional arrangement of ink blobs. But if we have to write ${\bigcup}\,(\,k\,=\,1\,)\,(\,n\,)\,(\,A\,\text{index}\,(\,k\,)\,)$ or something like that anyway, we have entered the realm of non-readabilty far enough to not need different sizes anyway

Answer (score 0):

Any of the above matter if you make it matter.  You can define your alphabet how you like.  If you want to define an alphabet with only $<$ or only $>$ because you can get by with just one, have at it.

Size can matter if you enjoy the benefits of capitalization.  $C$ and $c$, $O$ and $o$, $W$ and $w$ are just different sizes for the letters, but one marks the beginning of the first word in a sentence in formal English, and the other doesn't.

But in some cases the size doesn't really change the meaning;

$$[3x^2(3y^2 + z^3)]$$

and

$$\left[3x^2\left(3y^2 + z^3\right)\right]$$

mean the same thing, but one is slightly prettier to look at.